# Is there any other way to get property from bean in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, properties

If I want to get the property from a bean and use it for some Java Code. Such as, get the visitor count but not output it, just for some other use. I cannot use  because it'll output the value.

How can get the property but not output it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set property to any variable then you can process it.

```
<c:set var="name" scope="scope" value="expression"/>
```

for example :

```
<c:set var="visitorCount" scope="scope" value="someBean.counter"/>
```

even you can process it without setting

Answer (score 0):

This example retrieves a session-scoped bean and makes it available using the id myBean. Although it's not a good practice to have scriptlets in your jsp code, but one way is to call any method on the bean as shown below.

```
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" class="com.mycompany.MyBean" scope="session" />

<% myBean.getprop1(); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<jsp:useBean id ="object instance" class="full qualified path of ur class" scope="according to need"/>
<jsp:getProperty name="same as id" property="name of the property"/>`

> use according to this u must get ur result without using scripting....